# C++ Bitwise XOR optimization

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio, optimization, simd

I am attempting to find as many optimizations as I can for my password recovery code and I've been doing lots of simplification, for-loop unrolling, and lookup tables.

I've extracted a lot of performance doing that, and am thinking I will eventually have to start threading to get extra performance. But I was wondering if there's a potential x86-based vector/SIMD (SSE/AVX) based equivalent for this bitwise XOR.

```
    const uint8_t initialkey[8] = { 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef };
    uint8_t archivekey[8];
    archivekey[0] = initialkey[0] ^ passblock[0]; // Example: 01 XOR 32 (ASCII for 2) is 0x33
    archivekey[1] = initialkey[1] ^ passblock[1]; // Example: 23 XOR 39 (ASCII for 9) is 0x1a
    archivekey[2] = initialkey[2] ^ passblock[2]; // Example: 45 XOR 72 (ASCII for r) is 0x37
    archivekey[3] = initialkey[3] ^ passblock[3]; // Example: 67 XOR 36 (ASCII for 6) is 0x51
    archivekey[4] = initialkey[4] ^ passblock[4]; // Example: 89 XOR 35 (ASCII for 5) is 0xbc
    archivekey[5] = initialkey[5] ^ passblock[5]; // Example: ab XOR 78 (ASCII for x) is 0xd3
    archivekey[6] = initialkey[6] ^ passblock[6]; // Example: cd XOR 77 (ASCII for w) is 0xba
    archivekey[7] = initialkey[7] ^ passblock[7]; // Example: ef XOR 00 (ASCII for NOTHING) is 0xef
```

In this code, initialkey is always 0123456789abcdef, and passblock is what changes (as with the example of ascii "29r65xw").

Technically I guess I could replace the initialkey[] with the actual value (since it's always static).

But am I missing any tricks here to optimize how fast this would run- or am I just better off leaving this to the compiler to optimize? Perhaps with some data alignment? It just seems like this code is too simple and there'd be some way to do all 8 calls faster (outside of threading). I tried setting the archivekey manually just to speed test and didn't see any significant improvement, so I'm not expecting much, but I've love to learn a little bit about a topic I don't know anything about.

The code I have is being compiled with Xcode, VS2015, and I've tried the ICC as well, but VS2015 would be my main goal.

Comment: Yes, most SIMD instruction sets, including SSE, have an XOR instruction.  That should auto-vectorize as long as the compiler knows the arrays don't overlap.  (Use `__restrict__` if you compiler supports it).  Did you check that your compiler doesn't already optimize this to a single 64-bit XOR in an integer register?  (look at the asm output, the x86 instructions all have XOR in the name.  xor same,same is the zeroing idiom, so look for xor with two different operands.

Comment: If your compiler doesn't handle this, use a union: `union key { uint8_t bytes[8]; uint64_t u64; }`.  Do the xor on the u64 member, and read individual bytes out of the bytes[] member.  (This isn't portable ISO C++, but normal compilers support this type-punning idiom.  GNU C explicitly guarantees that it works, for example.)  Also, you could consider factoring out the xor, and just searching for an `archivekey`.  (Then once you find a working archivekey, apply the xor to get an ASCII passblock.) Not worth worrying about really, though, because a 64-bit xor is at least as cheap as a 64-bit add.

Comment: See [Agner Fog's optimizing C++ and optimizing assembly guides](http://agner.org/optimize/) and x86 instruction tables to learn more about how to make code run fast, especially on x86.

Comment: A byte array has no alignment. That can prevent using 64-bit instructions. Make sure those arrays are properly aligned by putting them in class type objects (I think but not sure that simply using `std::array` will suffice).

Comment: In F90 there are a heap of bit operations.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the pointers. I've gotten some improvements and will learn more as I delve into your links and suggestions. I especially like the factoring back from Archivekey, I hadn't thought of working backwards like that.